# What will happen after Visual Studio RC expires?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm now using VS 2012 Ultimate RC, which will expire in 10 days.

I've never used RCs before, so I don't know what will happen after they expire. Probably the IDE will be disabled? Or command line tools will be inaccessible?

Maybe someone knows official FAQs that explain these?

Comment: Even if it let you use the IDE, you would be breaching the license terms you accepted when you installed the program. You could as well use pirated version then, it would be about the same thing.

Comment: @MatějZábský - Telling uers to use a pirated version of an application is not being responsible member of our field.

Comment: @Ramhound I didn't tell him to use pirated version, I warned him from trying to make the RC version work beyond its expiration date.

Comment: @Ramhound Not understanding subtleties is even more hurtful to our field. He never told users to use pirated version, he made a comparison to push his point.

Comment: @Baboon - Being able to communicate is important. In his comparision he said that using a trial test version beyond the trial test period would be "about the samething" as using a pirated version of a fully functional program. Why not simply suggest using the free version of Visual Studio already offered instead?  Telling somebody this to me indicates some level of suggestion that using a pirated version would be about the samething as trying to extend the trial version and its not even remotely the samething.

Comment: @Ramhound Communication is important, so is grammar and spelling. When dealing with non-native English speakers you sometimes have to give some leeway. There was nothing in his post that suggested to use a pirated copy.

Comment: @James - I took it as advice to pirate the software in question.  At this point this extended discussion will not happen.

Comment: I have no intention to use the pirated version nor to make the RC version work beyond its expiration date. 
I'll explain a bit more. I usually play with C/C++ (and C#/F#, rarely). For personal hobby though, and not for work.
Generally I prefer using the VS command line, because it's quicker. Typing the codes using vim and running it in command prompt
is quicker than running the IDE.

Actually the reason I installed VS 2012 RC is updated compilers (and I can use the full version for a certain period freely :D).

Comment: Sure the IDE is nice, but I don't use it much, except for playing with Typescript and debugging C/C++ codes.

Somehow I assume only the GUI tools which will be disabled after expiration (the command line tools are still usable). Yes I know, it's a kinda
silly assumption, but it's better to ask than just assuming, right?

So, if VS 2012 RC will be disabled fully then it's fine with me. I can use the Express edition
Hopefully I make myself clear :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [comment](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasonz/archive/2012/05/31/announcing-the-release-candidate-rc-of-visual-studio-2012-and-net-framework-4-5.aspx?PageIndex=4) from Jeff Beehler (MSFT) indicates the RC will stop working.

> In the VS2012 Release Candidate license terms you'll find that the software will stop running on 15 January 2013.

Raymond Chen, tells a story about a previous RC versions of Windows [stopped working](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/05/21/9633075.aspx) after it expired.

> The evaluation period for this installation of Windows has expired. This system will shut down in 1 hour.

Comment: Please expand your answer and include a brief summary of what's included in the links. If those links die your answer has little value.